# error 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Tras realizar este programa me da un error del siguiente tipo:

> n = 2*n[i]
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Me gustaría saber que parte del código he de cambiar.

```
def arquimides(x):
    n = 6
    l = 1
    import math
    L = 2/math.sqrt(3)
    per = n*l/2
    PER = n*L/2
    print(17*' ', 'n', 17*' ', 'l',17*' ', 'L',17*' ', 'per',17*' ', 'PER')
    print(17*' ', n, 17*' ', l, 17*' ', L, 17*' ', per, 17*' ', PER)
    for i in range (x):
        n = 2*n[i]
        L = l[i]*L[i]/(l[i] + L[i])
        l= math.sqrt(L*[i]/2)
        per = n[i]*l[i]/2
        PER = n[i]*L[i]/2
        return print(10*' ', n, 10*' ', l, 10*' ', L, 10*' ', per, 10*' ', PER)
```

Answer (score 1):

El error `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` aparece debido a que en algún momento intentas aplicarle índices (*subscripts*) a una variable que es de tipo `int`.

Efectivamente, la expresión `n[i]` usa subíndices sobre la variable `n`, pero ésta no es una lista, sino un entero como vemos en `n = 6`.

Lo mismo ocurre con las variables `l` y `L` que inicializas con valores numéricos (en el caso de `L` es un `float`), pero más adelante en cambio intentas acceder con `l[i]` y `L[i]`.

### Actualización

Una vez Maria ha suministrado el enunciado del ejercicio que intentaba resolver, tengo más claro cómo abordarlo y puedo sugerirle mejoras en el código, como las siguientes:

1. No es necesario el uso de listas ni arrays, a menos que quieras ir acumulando en una lista lo que va saliendo para los diferentes valores de `n`, pero no parece que te pidan eso, así que puedes limitarte a imprimir por pantalla los resultados sin guardarlos en listas.
2. Aparentemente por tanto basta eliminar los `[i]` de todas partes en tu programa.
3. La línea que recalcula `l` dentro del `for` no parece corresponder a la que se daba en el enunciado, que decía `l'=sqrt(L'+l/2)`. Usas un producto en lugar de una suma y te falta usar `l` como parte de la expresión.
4. El `return` de la última línea sobraría, pues de lo contrario la función saldría en la primera iteración del bucle (además de que retornar lo que devuelve `print` no tiene sentido, pues `print` devuelve siempre `None`)
5. Un último detalle, el `import math` debería estar fuera de la función.

Con estas sugerencias tu código quedaría:

```
import math
def arquimides(x):
    n = 6
    l = 1
    L = 2/math.sqrt(3)
    per = n*l/2
    PER = n*L/2
    print(17*' ', 'n', 17*' ', 'l',17*' ', 'L',17*' ', 'per',17*' ', 'PER')
    print(17*' ', n, 17*' ', l, 17*' ', L, 17*' ', per, 17*' ', PER)
    for i in range (x):
        n = 2*n
        L = l*L/(l + L)
        l= math.sqrt(L+l/2)
        per = n*l/2
        PER = n*L/2
        print(10*' ', n, 10*' ', l, 10*' ', L, 10*' ', per, 10*' ', PER)
```

El cual ya se puede ejecutar sin errores, pero produce un resultado que me temo no es correcto. Ésta sería la salida del programa (para `x=5`):

```
          n                   l                   L                   per                   PER
          6                   1                   1.1547005383792517                   3.0                   3.4641016151377553
   12            1.0177909337689375            0.5358983848622455            6.106745602613625            3.215390309173473
   24            0.9273358762479919            0.3510563604921621            11.128030514975903            4.212676325905945
   48            0.8475385044421772            0.2546535783880865            20.340924106612253            6.1116858813140755
   96            0.7871384548501504            0.1958176948827938            37.78264583280722            9.399249354374103
   192            0.741874303108312            0.15680825418736846            71.21993309839796            15.053592401987373
```

Al margen de que las columnas no están bien alineadas (lo que podría arreglarse usando cadenas de formato apropiadas), los valores son lo que me preocupan ya que, si no entendí mal, lo que buscaba Arquímedes era una aproximación al número π, que sería tanto mejor cuanto mayor fuera `n`. En cambio los números que te salen van creciendo en lugar de acercarse a π.

Seguramente alguna de las fórmulas usadas no está correctamente copiada, o le faltan paréntesis en un numerador o denominador, o algo de eso. Pero desconozco la formulación exacta que Arquímedes hizo de este problema, por lo que no te puedo señalar exactamente dónde está el error.

Comment: me pide que dado n=6,l=1,L=2/sqrt(3), per=n*l/2 y PER=n*L/2                           Calcule una tabla en la cual ahora n´ va a ser 2*n,l'=sqrt(L'+l/2),L'=l*L/l+L,per=n'*l'/2 y PER=n'*L'/2

Comment: Sigo sin entenderlo... ¿Qué es nl? ¿Una variable nueva, o el producto de n por l? En el segundo caso no sería tan simple como `per = n*l/2`, `PER=n*L/2`? ¿A qué vienen todos los subíndices `[i]` si no hay ningún array ni lista en tu código?

Comment: la pregunta exactamente es esta:Arquímedes observó una circunferencia (en rojo, en la figura), un polígono inscrito en ella (azul) y otro circunscrito (amarillo). (V. figura en la otra columna de esta página.)

Comment: Y aprovechó el hecho de que la longitud de la circunferencia está entre los perímetro de esos dos polígonos: Recordemos que . Al dividir los tres perímetros por el diámetro de la circunferencia, dejó Arquímedes el valor de encerrado entre dos cocientes: Cuantos más lados tengan dichos polígonos, más cerca estarán esas cantidades

Comment: . Y así es como Arquímedes se propuso calcular los perímetros de polígonos de más y más caras, inscritos y circunscritos, hallando valores de , menores y mayores, pero muy, muy próximos al verdadero. Su plan fue empezar con un hexágono regular inscrito y otro circunscrito, y duplicar el número de lados sucesivamente: Y encontró que, si los lados de los hexágonos eran  l y L los de los dodecágonos eran: 
L'=l*L/l+L y l'=sqrt(L'+l/2)
Así, partió de una circunferencia de radio 1, en que los lados de los hexágonos son:
l=1 y L=SQRT(3)

Comment: Y pasó al dodecágono, al icosatetrágono (24 lados), etc. Mediante
 n´ =2*n,l'=sqrt(L'+l/2),L'=l*L/l+L,per=n'*l'/2 y PER=n'*L'/2 
Calcula un programa que genere una tabla cuando el poligonotenga seis lados ,12 , 24, etc

Comment: @maria Entiendo que se trata de un ejercicio de alguna asignatura. Intentaré ayudarte sin resolvértelo por completo. No obstante, te pido que este enunciado que has suministrado en estos cuatro últimos comentarios, lo copies en la pregunta original (puedes editarla), y luego borres estos comentarios, para que quien lo lea luego lo tenga más claro de antemano. Gracias

Comment: @maria edita la pregunta para añadir la información que pones en estos comentarios. Lee [ask] donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus preguntas y completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general.

Comment: mil graciasssss